# box-shadow won't cover all of accordion

Tags: html, css

I have this div accordion:

```
#accordion {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 900px;
  background: #93cede; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #93cede 0%, #75bdd1 41%, #49a5bf 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#93cede), color-stop(41%,#75bdd1), color-stop(100%,#49a5bf)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #93cede 0%,#75bdd1 41%,#49a5bf 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #93cede 0%,#75bdd1 41%,#49a5bf 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #93cede 0%,#75bdd1 41%,#49a5bf 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #93cede 0%,#75bdd1 41%,#49a5bf 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#93cede', endColorstr='#49a5bf',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;
  }
```

but the box shadow only covers half of the accordion..

Comment: What do you mean "half" post some more code or better yet a jsfiddle

Comment: Can you put the HTML code? By the way, it would be good a jsfiddle. Thanks! =)

Comment: Box shadow is only supposed to be on two sides of a rectangle (e.g. left and bottom, or right and top), not on all 4 sides...just like a real shadow.

Comment: ...although you may be able to achieve the look you want with careful positioning plus the use of the `inset` property - try an exaggerated value like `box-shadow: 0 0 5px 20px #888;` to see its effect.

Comment: @MattBrowne But what's the problem if he do that? If you think that way, in some cases, it can limit creativity.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique I'm saying that CSS box-shadow is not designed to put a shadow on all sides...the best you can do is to hack it to look close. I'm not talking about how it "should" look from an artistic perspective...I'm talking about the purpose of box-shadow. For shadow on all sides it would be better to either use an image, or perhaps two equally sized nested divs with box shadows in opposite directions to get the desired look.

Comment: It's works fine . why `only covers half` ?